# ROSJava on MacOS - Fail to build roscore

Tags: rosjava, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I execute

> ./gradlew install

in the rosjava_core directory, I receive the following exception:

> MessageInterfaceBuilder.java:158: cannot find symbol
> symbol  : method getJavaTypeName()
> location: class org.ros.internal.message.PrimitiveFieldType
>             primitiveFieldType.getJavaTypeName(), field.getName(), value));

Here is the full stack trace:

> org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':rosjava_bootstrap:compileJava'.
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:68)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:34)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.CacheLockHandlingTaskExecuter$1.run(CacheLockHandlingTaskExecuter.java:34)
> at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess$2.create(DefaultCacheAccess.java:200)
>     at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:172)
>     at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:198)
>     at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.longRunningOperation(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:111)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.java:83)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.CacheLockHandlingTaskExecuter.execute(CacheLockHandlingTaskExecuter.java:32)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:55)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:57)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:41)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:51)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:52)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:42)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:247)
>     at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.executeTask(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:192)
>     at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.doExecute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:177)
>     at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:83)
>     at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:36)
>     at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
>     at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
> at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:67)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter$1.run(TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter.java:31)
> at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess$1.create(DefaultCacheAccess.java:111)
>     at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:126)
>     at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:109)
>     at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.useCache(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:103)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.java:79)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter.execute(TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter.java:29)
>     at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
>     at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
> at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:67)
>     at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
>     at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
>     at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:54)
>     at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:155)
>     at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:110)
>     at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:78)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:45)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.Build.run(Build.java:67)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.Build.run(Build.java:63)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:45)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:45)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:24)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ReturnResult.execute(ReturnResult.java:34)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$4.call(ForwardClientInput.java:116)
> at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$4.call(ForwardClientInput.java:114)
>     at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:114)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:61)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.doBuild(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:49)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.HandleStop.execute(HandleStop.java:36)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.CatchAndForwardDaemonFailure.execute(CatchAndForwardDaemonFailure.java:32)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.HandleClientDisconnectBeforeSendingCommand.execute(HandleClientDisconnectBeforeSendingCommand.java:21)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StopConnectionAfterExecution.execute(StopConnectionAfterExecution.java:27)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DefaultDaemonCommandExecuter.executeCommand(DefaultDaemonCommandExecuter.java:55)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon$1$1.run(Daemon.java:123)
>     at org.gradle.messaging.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:66)
> Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.jdk6.Jdk6JavaCompiler.execute(Jdk6JavaCompiler.java:42)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.jdk6.Jdk6JavaCompiler.execute(Jdk6JavaCompiler.java:33)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.delegateAndHandleErrors(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:95)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:48)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:34)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.DelegatingJavaCompiler.execute(DelegatingJavaCompiler.java:29)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.DelegatingJavaCompiler.execute(DelegatingJavaCompiler.java:20)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.IncrementalJavaCompilerSupport.execute(IncrementalJavaCompilerSupport.java:33)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.IncrementalJavaCompilerSupport.execute(IncrementalJavaCompilerSupport.java:23)
>     at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.Compile.compile(Compile.java:60)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.BeanDynamicObject$MetaClassAdapter.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:196)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.BeanDynamicObject.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:102)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDynamicObject.invokeMethod(CompositeDynamicObject.java:99)
> at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.Compile_Decorated.invokeMethod(Unknown Source)
> at org.gradle.util.ReflectionUtil.invoke(ReflectionUtil.groovy:23)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$4.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:150)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$4.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:145)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:477)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:466)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:60)
>     ... 76 more

Thanks for the help.  Does this have something to do with running ROSJava on MacOSX?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34857/rosjava-on-macos---fail-to-build-roscore/) by [amittleider](https://answers.ros.org/users/2448/amittleider/) on ROS Answers with karma: 227 on 2012-05-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I edited the source code of MessageInterfaaceBuilder.java:158 to read:
"builder.append(String.format("  static final %s %s = %s;\n", field.getJavaTypeName(), field.getName(), value));"

instead of:
"builder.append(String.format("  static final %s %s = %s;\n", primitiveFieldType.getJavaTypeName(), field.getName(), value));"

and this appears to fix the compilation issue.  However, I don't know if this is what the code intended to say.  The pubsub tutorial also now works.

---

Originally posted by [amittleider](https://answers.ros.org/users/2448/amittleider/) with karma: 227 on 2012-05-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) on 2012-05-29**:
See issue http://code.google.com/p/rosjava/issues/detail?id=117